# How to remove dependencies in installshield?

Tags: installation, dependencies, installshield

While building my install shield project i get the following error -

1. Error retrieving dependency Microsoft_VC90_CRT_x86.0138F525... ERROR CODE - 4072
2. Error retrieving dependency policy_9_0_Microsoft_VC90_CRT_x86.521... ERROR CODE - 4072

Can anyone tell me how to remove these dependencies? I am new to install shield and i am editing someone else's project so any tutorials/links will be helpful.
I am using Install shield 2012 Premier edition.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have merge modules included in your project. Check your merge modules and see if any of the module has some dependency for it. This [link](http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/installshield15helplib/IHelpMergeModules.htm) may help you.